# Is it possible to restore a file overwritten by git checkout?

Tags: recovery, git-checkout

I had uncommitted changes and ran

```
gco . /path/to/file.js
```

Needless to say, I lost all my changes.  Is there any way to undo this? Changes were not staged and didn’t have tabs open. Wish they had been. Using VSCode(with git lens) for an editor. Don’t have time machine enabled.

Comment: Um, no. If the changes were never committed, and you overwrote the files, there's no way to undo that at all. Git can't help with changes it knows nothing about yet.

Comment: @KenWhite I was afraid this would be the case, thanks anyway.

Comment: It depends on your editor: said editor might have a local history of your file (independent of Git)

Comment: Were the changes ever staged?

Comment: As VonC mentioned, if your editor has a local history of your file or if by any change you still have that file tab open in your editor...

Comment: Like @JackGore asked you, there is a possibility if the changes has been staged... Did you staged the file?

Comment: If you are using macOS or Windows **and** the Time Machine/backup is enabled then there is a chance to recover a slightly outdated version of it from the backup (the Time Machine on macOS runs every hour, the backup on Windows runs as you configured it).

Comment: Changes were not staged and didn’t not have tabs open. Wish they had been. Using VSCode for editor. Don’t have time machine enabled.

Comment: So... next time: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AronDCurzon.LocalHistoryforVisualStudio

Comment: @VonC very cool! thanks

Answer (score 1):

So to recap:

- a modified file was checked out (reset to HEAD)
- said modification was never added to the index
- no other history mechanism was in place

  - either OS-based, like [MacOS Time Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_(macOS)) or
  - an [IDE local history such as Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm).

Then yes, the local modifications are likely to be lost.
A very remote recovery possibility might be a file recovery tool (on Mac for instance, [Disk Drill 3](https://www.cleverfiles.com/recover-deleted-files-mac.html)).
But if there was too much hard-drive activity since the checkout, that should not work anyway.

Working with an IDE like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), I would recommend installing and activating an extension like "[Local History for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=xyz.local-history)"